# Merge 3 fields into 1 value - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
id  e_id        e_nm        e_value             line_num
59  BHT03-01    Ref ID      04/18/1820          4
59  BHT03-02                38                  4
59  BHT03-03                10                  4
59  ABC03-01    Ref ID      04/18/1820          4
59  ABC03-02                38                  4
59  ABC03-03                10                  4
60  BHT03-01    Ref ID      05/09/1820          4
60  BHT03-02                52                  4
60  BHT03-03                43                  4
```

I need to concatenate each BHT03-01, BHT03-02 and BHT03-03 separated by : into 1 BHT03-01 for each id and line_num.

All other e_id apart from BHT03-01 should be unaffected.

Here is the output:

table1

```
id  e_id        e_nm        e_value             line_num
59  BHT03-01    Ref ID      04/18/1820:38:10    4
59  BHT03-02                38                  4
59  BHT03-03                10                  4
59  ABC03-01    Ref ID      04/18/1820          4
59  ABC03-02                38                  4
59  ABC03-03                10                  4
60  BHT03-01    Ref ID      05/09/1820:52:43    4
60  BHT03-02                52                  4
60  BHT03-03                43                  4
```

Once I get this table, I also have to drop all the rows with BHT03-02, BHT03-03.

How can I do it in Oracle SQL?

Comment: After this is done, I am going to drop BHT03-02 and BHT03-03.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information and update the expected output to be the final result set. This is important info that could affect the answer! Also, might be worth including non-BHT% rows in the input and output data, so we can see what should/should not happen to those rows.

Comment: Added extra information. Also, dropping BHT03-02 and BHT03-03 would be done later.

Comment: Done later... after some other not-related-to-your-table processing? Or can the delete be done at the same time as the update of the BHT03-01 row?

Comment: So, you want to do the same for all e_id types? Are they all of the format XXXNN-NN? Can we safely take the first 5 characters as a group? or do we have to take all but the last 3 characters?

Comment: I just want this done specifically for BHT03-01, BHT03-02 and BHT03-03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement will do the update and delete in one go:

```
MERGE INTO table1 tgt
USING (SELECT ID,
              e_id,
              line_num,
              listagg(e_value, ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e_id) OVER (PARTITION BY id, line_num) e_value,
              CASE WHEN e_id IN ('BHT03-02', 'BHT03-03') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END del
       FROM   table1
       WHERE  e_id IN ('BHT03-01', 'BHT03-02', 'BHT03-03')) src
  ON (tgt.id = src.id AND tgt.line_num = src.line_num AND tgt.e_id = src.e_id) -- or whatever the unique identifiers are for the table1 rows
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.e_value = src.e_value
  DELETE WHERE src.del = 'Y';
```

And here's [a demo of it working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=984617a7a00103ffe120ea7311ed9791).

Comment: This is why it's important to give as much information as possible about your problem - don't just break it down into the specific step you're trying to achieve. Context is everything!

Answer (score 2):

Given that the updated value in the `e_value` column is actually derived data, I suggest just creating a computed column when you select, maybe in a view:

```
SELECT
    id,
    e_id,
    e_nm,
    CASE WHEN e_id LIKE 'BHT03%' AND
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, line_num ORDER BY e_id) = 1
         THEN LISTAGG(e_value, ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e_id)
               OVER (PARTITION BY id, line_num)
         ELSE e_value END AS e_value,
    line_num
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    id,
    e_id;
```

The above logic detects the first row in each `id` group, which should correspond to the row with the date in the `e_value` column.  In the case of the first row, it displays a colon-separated concatenation of all the records in the `id` group, otherwise it just repeats the `e_value` which is already there.

Comment: The logic needs to be specific to BHT03 e_id and NOT for others. Also, we need to consider id and line_num

Comment: Do you want to see records which are not `BHT03%`?  If so, what happens with those other records.  I updated my answer, which should at least partially resolve your requirements.

Comment: I want to update in the table. Is there a way I can update the e_value? OR can I create a new column in the table with ONLY BHT values?

Comment: I edited my logic again so that your computed value would only appear for `BHT` values (and then only in the first row).  Otherwise, the original `e_value` would appear.

Comment: It gives me error - ORA-00905: missing keyword - on this line -                OVER (PARTITION BY id, line_num) e_value

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in there.  Please try it again.

Comment: It I don't put - where element_id LIKE 'BHT03%', then the aggregation doesn't work. Is that right?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but for non `BHT03` records the `LISTAGG` logic would _not_ be hit, meaning it would always just show the original `e_value`.

Comment: I mean if I run the query as is, it doesn't show me aggregated value. But if I add - where element_id LIKE 'BHT03%', it shows me aggregated value in BHT03-01.

Comment: What you are describing doesn't make sense.  Adding a `WHERE` clause can't make _more_ records/columns appear, only fewer.  I believe my answer to be correct given the sample data above.  You may have to do some work to make the answer fit your actual data.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense. Not sure why it is happening though. Weird.

Comment: Probably because the `partition by`s needs to include `case when e_id LIKE 'BHT03%' then 1 end` in it?